# Estimate contract transactions fees

Tags: erc-20, gas, gas-estimate

I swapped some BNB to Cricket tokens on Pancakeswap and I had a bad surprise when I had to swap back those crickets to BNB. Indeed the transaction fees were very high (7.41$) as you can see here: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc74741f8ff1ee007f3e963016232d9a05cec7298e47a5633302fda6b43c580ff

It looks like it's a common practice for shitcoins to add a lot of fees to transactions and I was wondering if it's possible to estimate gas fees before buying tokens. I've found a website called tokensniffer that is providing the fees (here 15%) and would like to know how to compute this percentage by myself. https://tokensniffer.com/token/1znk61sc2q1qvqfds8ad68bif2v24uxmkfkl0cqi1pk649dbsgqgaz9kkkaz?h=2898

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks that TokenSniffer took the info about 15% from the BSC scan link you have provided.
Go to section Section contract - totalBuyFees, totalSellFees.

Comment: Hello v1bio. It works for few contracts but not for all. Also I've found two other tools giving the taxes information, but with slightly different values : 
https://honeypot.is/?address=0x5f26154d757874e1cd8d06637561ac47efa666ef
https://app.marketmove.ai/token/0x5f26154d757874e1cd8d06637561ac47efa666ef/audit